# Is it possible to generate JPEG progressive thumbnails?

Tags: media, thumbnails

I noticed the even if I upload a progressive JPEG in Wordpress media when it generates the thumbnails it creates them in baseline format instead of original progressive format.

Is it possible to change this behavior using some hook?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if Wordpress has a way to handle this or if its based on server features and the ability of PHP but I think you could achieve this by 3rd party plugins such as Smush.i­t if I am not mistaken due to the fact that the image needs to be converted this way.

Comment: Thank you, I would like to avoid. if possible, services like this because usually they are are not free. I prefer create already optimized images locally and the upload on Wordpress, but it is a pity that the thumbnails are not progressive because they negatively impact on page loading times.